# Typescript compiler cannot find Jquery type definitions even though they are already installed

Tags: jquery, typescript, typescript-typings, yarnpkg

I'm trying to run `tsc` to compile all my typescript files. It had complained about not being able to find name `$` for Jquery.

```
src/public/js/main.ts:68:15 - error TS2581: Cannot find name '$'. Do you need to install type definitions for jQuery? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/jquery
```

I then installed the jquery type definitions that it had told me to install (`yarn add @types/jquery --dev`). I tried running the compiler again and it still complained saying it cannot find name `$` despite the fact jquery types are already installed

package.json https://hastebin.com/segaxiyuyo.json
tsconfig.json https://hastebin.com/culonoluno.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add `/node_modules/@types` to your tsconfig `typeRoots: ["./src/typings", "/node_modules/@types"]` since you are overriding it